# Making an instance of GraphDB on Docker

Tags: docker, graphdb

I am trying to make an instance of GraphDB on Docker. After creating the instance, I need to make a repository to import the data to the instance. However, when I make a repository, it says that the repository does not exist. When I use the loadrdf command to import data I receive an error regarding that the repository does not exist.

`dist/bin/loadrdf -f -i repo-test -m parallel /opt/graphdb/home/data/*.ttl`

Answer (score 0):

The default data location of GraphDB is the `data` sub-directory of GraphDB's home directory, which in turn defaults to the distribution directory.

For the docker image this is `/opt/graphdb/dist`, so the default data directory is `/opt/graphdb/dist/data`.

But also in the docker image the default home is changed to `/opt/graphdb/home`, so the data directory becomes `/opt/graphdb/home/data`. This is done by passing the `-Dgraphdb.home=/opt/graphdb/home` java option when starting GraphDB.

So, when you created your repository it was created at `/opt/graphdb/home/data/repositories/repo-test`.

Your problem is that the `loadrdf` tool doesn't know about the changed home directory.
To overcome this try exporting the `GDB_JAVA_OPTS` variable with value `-Dgraphdb.home=/opt/graphdb/home` before running `loadrdf`, or as a one-liner:

`GDB_JAVA_OPTS='-Dgraphdb.home=/opt/graphdb/home' ./dist/bin/loadrdf -f -i repo-test -m parallel /opt/graphdb/home/data/*.ttl`